# Permission denied while copying files from one server to another

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, scp

Permission denied while copying files from one server to another after logging in as sudo user.

scp -p file x123@targethost:/opt/apps

Comment: Are you entering the correct password?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try running sudo or switch user (su) to the user who created the files?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).